# iOS Application exiting voluntarily when embedded with custom framework

Tags: ios

I have embedded a custom framework in my app. When running the app, I get the error:

> Application exited voluntarily"
>
> Aug 25 09:57:22 iPhone SpringBoard[54] : Application 'UIKitApplication:com.mobileiron.enterprise.phoneatwork.TestFramework[0xe161]' exited voluntarily.
>   Aug 25 09:57:22 iPhone assertiond[64] : Could not set priority of  to 2, priority: No such process
>   Aug 25 09:57:22 iPhone assertiond[64] : Could not set priority of  to 4096, priority: No such process
>   Aug 25 09:57:23 iPhone wifid[37] : WiFi:[462214643.2

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add all exception break points and what happens?

Comment: Someone is calling `exit`, it seems. Breakpoint on `exit` symbol and see who calls it and why.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Adding the above does not cause the breakpoints to be hit. However, i enabled "Log Dyld API Usage" and "Log Library Loads" and this print the following: 

_dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide(0)
_dyld_get_image_header(0)
0d43f22bcf4140701d4c3fd9cab89e0e5b4735a9